# Ajax no envia valor dato a PHP

Tags: php, ajax

Tengo que llevar el valor de un SELECT a un archivo PHP mediante una función que ejecuta un AJAX.
Codigo SELEC.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <label class="input-group-text" for="selectExpedi">Seleciona:</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <select class="custom-select" id="selectExpedi">
                                        <!-- aqui va el php -->
                                    </select>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col">
                                        <button type="button"  class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary btn-lg btn-block" onclick="cargarHoja()" >Cargar Hoja de Ruta</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>      
                        </div>   
                    </div>
```

El botón llama a esta función:

Que recoge el valor del SELECt correctamente como se puede ver en la consola.
El valor es 107435.

[image: foto de la consola]

Este valor lo quiero pasar con la función a la que llama el botón que es esta:

```
function cargarHoja(){

var exp=$("#selectExpedi").val();

console.log(exp);

$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:'hoja.php',
    data: exp,
    success: function(data) {


    }
});
```

}

Pero cuando depuro el PHP  que tiene simplemente este código:

```
<?php

require_once "conexion.php";
var_dump ($_GET);


$a=$_GET['exp'];
```

Me encuentro con este error. Adjunto foto de la pantalla.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Como se ve en el depurador, $_POST tiene el valor 107435 como debe de ser, pero me devuelve un error.

Comment: Tienes que poner el `data`de este modo: **`data: { exp: exp },`** [Revisa los ejemplos en la documentación](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Se trata de enviar un objeto donde, el dato de la izquierda es el índice, y el dato de la derecha es el valor. Por ejemplo aquí: `data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }` en el `GET` buscarías por `$_GET['name']` y por `$_GET['location']`

Comment: Perfecto. Esa es la solución. Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la función **AJAX**, cuando envías por post el valor de la variable te falta un índice para la misma. Prueba con:

```
function cargarHoja(){

var exp=$("#selectExpedi").val();

console.log(exp);

$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:'hoja.php',
    data: {
        exp: exp
    },
    success: function(data) {


    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

En PHP estás buscando un request de tipo `GET` pero en AJAX estás haciendo un request tipo `POST`, para ver lo que estás recibiendo en PHP usa lo siguiente:

```
echo 'GET: ' . print_r($_GET, true) . PHP_EOL;
echo 'POST: ' . print_r($_POST, true) . PHP_EOL;
echo 'REQUEST: ' . print_r($_REQUEST, true) . PHP_EOL;
```

Recuerda que tanto `GET` como `POST` se encuentran también en `$_REQUEST`.

Por último, si vas a usar `GET`, entonces tu llamada Ajax debe lucir así:

```
$.ajax({
  type:"GET",
  url:'hoja.php',
  data: {
    exp: exp
  },
  success: function(data) {

  }
});
```

Comment: Tienes razón. Pero al corregirlo pasa lo mismo. La respuesta correcta es la del comentario numero 3. Gracias